# "is changed" vs "has changed"

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense

In the following podcast at 1:57 the reporter appears to say: "How is your life changed in the last few years?"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2DFyqiS-ZCY#t=126

I'd like to understand why not "has changed" is being used and what the justification for "is changed" is. Anybody, please?

I appreciate your kind help.

Comment: I'm quite certain that she said *has changed*. I think it would've gone unnoticed if I listened to it without your mentioning of "is changed".

Comment: I think she's quite clearly saying ***is***, but I don't attach any significance to this because 1) - she's obviously *not* a native speaker, and 2) it's perfectly credible (certainly in a "conversational" context, or to any but the most extreme pedant) to use present tense anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This sentence is not grammatically correct in modern usage, at least not in American English. I see that they are speaking British English, so maybe there is some common usage that I am not aware of. However, to my understanding, you are right that it should be "How has your life changed" not "How is your life changed."

This speaker may be trying to sound old fashioned or "proper." In archaic English (especially archaic British English), the intransitive verb "to be" was previously used in some situations where we now use "to have." This is not commonly used today. Since this is an ELL video, I wonder if an employee on the staff maybe insisted that this old construction was the "most correct."

In [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/342140/difference-between-is-come-and-has-come), user CDR quotes Quackenbos in An English Grammar (1887):

> In old writers we sometimes find the perfect of certain intransitive
> verbs formed with am instead of have, and the pluperfect with was
> instead of had. Thus: "Winter is [has] come"; "they are [have]
> arrived"; "when they were [had] gone"; "happiness was [had] flown."
> These forms are now rarely used, and should be avoided. Do not take
> them for passive tenses, which they resemble, but parse thus: Is come
> is an intransitive verb, used for has come; in the indicative mood,
> perfect tense

Answer (score -2):

*Is changed* uses the [passive voice.](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/passive.htm) It's a way of reporting on the *state* of the thing you're talking about. "Has changed"  would have the same meaning, but it uses the active voice instead.

If the subject performs the action, we're using the active voice. If the subject has an action performed on it, we're using the passive voice:

1. The event has changed your life **(active)**
2. Your life has been changed by the event **(passive)**

Comment: I don't see how active/passive is relevant to OP's specific question (which is "active" voice regardless of whether the question is framed as *How **is** it changed?* or *How **was** it changed?*).

Comment: "How is it changed? or How was it changed?"  --- those aren't the two choices OP gave, they asked for the difference between "How is your life changed" and "How *has* your life changed"  Explaining the two voices answers why "has changed" wasn't used, and explaining what the passive voice is used for answers the question: "What the justification for _is changed_ is"

Comment: Also, "How is it changed?" or "How was it changed?" are most certainly in the passive voice, not active. See the link in the answer: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/passive.htm

Comment: I can see what you're getting at, but it's not obvious to me that *"How is it changed?"* representd "passive voice", as opposed to, say, *"How is it different?"* (of which I assume you'd make no such claim).

Comment: FYI, I contacted the publisher with the same question and here's what I received as a reply: "Having checked  the video podcasts are authentic interviews with real people who obviously make mistakes especially when they are being interviewed (and especially if they are not native speakers).  The podcasts are designed to help learners cope with language as it is really spoken ...not how it appears in text books. So the answer is that it is a mistake but it's not something we would want to correct as that would impair the authenticity of the material."

Comment: You see I am a teacher of English (non-native) and I am confused about why the publisher would want to publish podcast material that is not grammatically correct i.e. in line with the corresponding course book where proper grammar is taught. The presenter in the podcast is from BBC - one would expect this fact in combination with the material that is designed for language learners, will be something that language learners can rely on as a learning guide.

Comment: This is just connected speech error. Everyone makes these kinds of errors when speaking.