# Difference between "is come" and "has come"

Tags: grammar, past-tense

What is the difference between the following two:

(A) The time is come for me to reveal what has lain hidden in my heart for so long.
(B) The time has come for me to reveal what has lain hidden in my heart for so long.

Comment: To say something **is** come or gone (e.g. 'the time is come') is old fashioned. Using 'has' is normal in modern English.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Harvey. Our paths have crossed again! Your contribution is greatly appreciated. I feel my English would improve in leaps and bounds if I had access to someone as competent as you on a much more regular basis.

Comment: I think "is come" is an archaic expression that means the same thing that "has come" means today. The phrase "is gone" used to mean what "has gone" means today, but now the meaning of "is gone" is often "is absent."

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Always old-fashioned for _come_, yes, but only old-fashioned for _gone_ when it’s the participle form of _go_, rather than a plain adjective meaning ‘no longer here’; and there’s a lot of overlap where both can work. “Is he gone?” and “Has he gone?” are both standard, but while “Has he gone to work?” is equally standard, “Is he gone to work?” is old-fashioned or dialectal.

Comment: Beside the point, but the second one sounds odd because it's mixing old-fashioned with new. I'd put "what lain has hidden" instead.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Would it be safe to say that "is gone" has obtained passive connotations? That is, while not a true passive, it implies that whatever 'is gone' didn't necessarily leave under its own power, while 'has gone' implies agency?

Comment: @NoName I don’t think it’s necessarily passive-like (since there is no notion of an external agent), but the difference definitely does align somewhat with agency, though I think more significantly with stativeness.

Answer (score 12):

> The time **has** come...

is standard English, and is the version that's used today.

---

On the other hand,

> The time **is** come...

sounds weird today and uses the archaic 'to be come' construction.

﻿Here is Quackenbos in [*An English Grammar* (1887):](https://onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/webbin/book/lookupid?key=ha010103137)

> In old writers we sometimes find the perfect of certain intransitive verbs formed with *am* instead of *have*, and the pluperfect with *was* instead of *had*. Thus: "Winter is [has] come"; "they are [have] arrived"; "when they were [had] gone"; "happiness was [had] flown."
> These forms are now rarely used, and should be avoided. Do not take them for passive tenses, which they resemble, but parse thus: *Is come* is an intransitive verb, used for *has come*; in the indicative mood, perfect tense, &c

Comment: Of course not all that relevant to this question but: the fact that it's archaic doesn't mean that it's entirely unused today. At least in my sociocultural environment, I could easily imagine announcing that they are leaving a party with "the time is come for me to depart, farewall all!" I would obviously immediately recognize that as an attempt to be funny (or at least a bit eccentric) by intentionally using an old-fashioned construction though, and (hopefully) not how they'd typically speak.

Comment: Is this perhaps the same thing as in German with haben/sein in perfect. Sein being used with motion and transformation verbs and haben with most others?

Comment: @Simppa Sort of, yes. English usage used to be closer to the German (and French) usage, but has since switched to using _have_ instead of _be_ almost everywhere. The same thing happened in Spanish, incidentally.