# Is the order arrived?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-meaning, adjectives, questions

Our teacher keeps telling us that * Is the order arrived? * is grammatically correct and added that Arrived here functions as an adjective. Anyone can help us solve the problem if there is one. Thank you

Comment: It sounds like the English of several hundred years ago. See [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/342140/difference-between-is-come-and-has-come).

Comment: Does your teacher by any chance speak French? It sounds like the *passé composé*. Or, as @KateBunting says, like the English of a few centuries ago.

Comment: **Has** the order arrived?

Answer (score 2):

On this occasion, your teacher is incorrect.

It should be:

> "***Has** the order arrived?*"

'Arrived' is not an adjective - it is the past tense of the verb *to arrive*, so it isn't correct to use that with the present tense 'is'. The alternative would be to use an alternative word in the present tense, such as "*is the order **here**?*".

*However*... in this modern world of e-commerce it is increasingly common to see words like 'arrived' or 'delivered' used as a *status* of an order or delivery. In such a context, it would be an adjective, describing the *state* of the order, not describing the actual contents or physical whereabouts of the order. That doesn't apply to your example, but it might be the source of the confusion. We would still say, for example, "*my order **has been** delivered*", but we might say, after checking the status of a delivery on an e-commerce site, something like "*the status of my order **is** delivered*".